# How can you access private string variables using member functions?

Tags: c++, function, member

I want to output the values of the private class members `Bankcode` and `AgentName`. How can I do this from within my `main()` function, or in general, outside of the `BOURNE` class.

My initial code attempts are below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class BOURNE
{
    string Bankcode ={"THE SECRET CODE IS 00071712014"} ; /*private by default*/

    string AgentName={"Jason Bourne"};                   /*private by default*/
public:    
    void tryToGetSecretCodeandName(string theName ,string theCode);    //trying to get the private   

    void trytoGetAgentName( string name); // try to get name
};
//***********************defining member function**************************************

void BOURNE::tryToGetSecretCodeandName(string theName, string theCode)  //member defining function
{
   Bankcode=theCode;    //equalling name to the code here 

   AgentName=theName;   //the samething here

   cout<<theCode<<"\n"<<theName; //printing out the values
}
//************************main function*****************************
int main()
{
   BOURNE justAnyObject;  //making an object to the class
   justAnyObject.tryToGetSecretCodeandName();
   return 0;    
}
```

Comment: What's the question? You can set the values this way, but it won't tell you what they initially were

Comment: I don't understand this. Nothing in your code attempts to retrieve the values of the private members.

Comment: look, all I need is this line here  cout<<theCode<<"\n"<<theName;    but as you see I can't print out the BankCode adn Agent name just print them on the screen nothing else , my question is why it works for int but not for string or characters? why I can't access the private in the class with string type ?

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate? Maybe show the output you get, and what you're hoping to get? Along with a comparison to `int`, if that behaves differently

Comment: it works for integers but all I need is to get this output             THE SECRET CODE IS 00071712014                                     Jason Bourne                                                               but the problem is it will not compile not in code blocks and neither in visual studio 2013 , strange , now I got stuck here

Answer (score 1):

**Third Answer**

Your code has two 'getter' style functions, but neither one takes no arguments. That is, both of your functions require arguments to be passed.

Your main function is calling `get...CodeandName()`, which has no arguments. As such, you get a compiler error, probably complaining about valid signatures, or arguments passed.

**Edited Answer**
If you only want to get the values, the typical (as far as I am aware) implementation is something like

```
std::string BOURNE::getCode()
{
    return Bankcode;
}

std::string BOURNE::getName()
{
    return AgentName;
}

int main()
{
    BOURNE myAgent;
    cout<< "The agent's name is : " << myAgent.getName() << endl;
    cout<< "The agent's code is : " << myAgent.getCode() << endl;
}
```

**Original Answer, left in because I feel like it's more useful**

I suspect what you're asking is if you could do something like

```
void BOURNE::tryToGetSecretCodeandName(string theName, string theCode)
{
    if (Bankcode == theCode) {
        cout<< "You correctly guessed the code : " << Bankcode << endl;
    }
    if (AgentName == theName) {
        cout << "You correctly guessed the agent's name : " << AgentName << endl;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to repeatedly guess at the name, and get output when you're correct.

If you wanted to disable this kind of guessing, then you could consider creating a new class (possibly derived from/based on `std::string` - but see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006860/why-should-one-not-derive-from-c-std-string-class) for reasons to be careful!) and implement an `operator==` function which always returned `false`.

Comment: please all I need to Print the Bankcode and AgentName but it will not compile and it's like I can't get access to them? I don't understand, it works for int but not string or characters , please help

Comment: Edited to reflect your request - if this is what you wanted say and I'll tidy up.

Comment: you know what ? I am studying C++ and I want to understand it logically, I know other ways to show this code and to works but all I want is to understand where is my mistake, and what is wrong with it, Return-Type class-name ::function-name(argument declarations) { function-body } , this should work but , why is not work with me?

Comment: You have no function with signature `tryToGetSecretCodeandName()`. Your functions (both, now) take arguments. Giving us the compilation errors you're hitting would be helpful if it's not this.

Comment: i think it has something with what you just said .no matching function for call to 'BOURNE::tryToGetSecretCodeandName()'|

Comment: Good stuff... Your problem is (you guessed it!) you have no matching function call to ... . You can fix this by adding a new function (taking no arguments), or alternatively by giving arguments to your function call in your `main()` function. The first is probably clearer given your intentions however - if you only want to print values, then you don't need arguments, right?

Comment: I gave arguments to my function in main but it is still expecting something else from me like in the error shows-----------expected primary-expression before 'theName'|

Comment: It's expecting the word "string" before theName. If you already have the word in place, check your semicolons, especially on the previous line.