# Overloading [] in subclassed C++ string

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, subclassing

What is the proper thing for me to return here?

```
char BCheckString::operator[](int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || this->length() <= index)
    {
        throw IndexOutOfBounds();
        ???Do I need to return something here???
    }
    else
    {
        return ?????;
    }
}
```

I tried `return this[index]` but VS2013 says: "no suitable conversion function from "BCheckString" to "char" exists. And I have no idea what to return after the throw.

I have:

```
class BCheckString : public string
{
private:
    bool checkBounds();
public:
    BCheckString(string initial_string);
    char operator[](int index);
    class IndexOutOfBounds{};
};
```

and

```
BCheckString::BCheckString(string initial_string) : string(initial_string)
{
}

char BCheckString::operator[](int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || this->length() <= index)
    {
        //throw IndexOutOfBounds();
        cout << "index out of bounds" << endl;
        return 'A';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'A';
    }
}
```

Obviously this is homework ;)

Comment: Why are you publicly deriving from `std::string`?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006860/why-should-one-not-derive-from-c-std-string-class

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie god save us. Theachers tell their students to derive from classes which are not designed to be derived. That's why most software is f***ed up.

Comment: Anyway, I see the answers down here will help you solve your problem. I suggest that you also take the quote from "Effective C++" that explains why you shouldn't derive from `std::string` and show it to your teacher (after you understood it, that is).

Comment: Indeed, I wonder how much bad code would break if std::string was changed to "final".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While observing that what you're doing here is unnecessary, the syntax is thus:

```
return string::operator[](index);
```

You're calling the `operator[]` of your `string` parent.  This should be preferred to using `c_str` because `string::operator[]` does bounds checking in debug builds.

It's also worth noting that `.at` already does bounds checking in release builds, and throws `std::out_of_range`.

For the first question, no.  After throwing an exception, you don't need to have a return statement.  In fact, if you do, the compiler may warn you about "unreachable code".

Comment: In fact, the proper implementation (in as much such nonsense can ever be properly implemented) would simply by `{ return string::at(index); }`

Answer (score 3):

First, deriving from `std::string` is not recommended:  [Why should one not derive from c++ std string class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006860/why-should-one-not-derive-from-c-std-string-class)

As to your questions:

1) After `throw` you don't return anything.

2) Your attempt to use `operator[]` is incorrect as you are not calling the parent class's `std::string::operator[]`.

To call the correct `operator[]`:

```
 else
 {
    return std::string::operator[](index);
 }
```

Comment: `I tried return this[index] `  That's what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a pointer, therefore `this[index]` will erroneously consider `this` as pointing to an array of instances to access the `index`-th of them. That will be an instance of the class itself and there's no implicit conversion from that to the declared return type `char` (this is what the error message is complaining about).

You need to get the char from the base string, and this is done with

```
return this->string::operator[](index);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you derived from std::string you can just use c_str() method to access data.

```
return this->c_str()[index];
```