# error: expected class-name before ‘{’

Tags: c++, inheritance

This is my code, I include string only in the header word.h. I don't understand where the problem is.

```
#ifndef WORD_H
#define WORD_H

#include <string>


class word : public string
{
    private:
         static string valid_ch;
    public:
        word() {}
        word(const string&);
        static word extract(const string&, size_type&);
};

#endif
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate

Comment: Read up on "namespaces" in your favorite C++ reference.

Comment: Do you really need a class "word"?  Unlike Java and C#, C++ doesn't require that all methods, functions and variables reside in a class.  You could have a free standing function to extract a word from a string.

Comment: string lives in the std namespace - try std::string - but this does not look like it is going to end well

Comment: Is not a good practice to derive from `std::string` take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006860/why-should-one-not-derive-from-c-std-string-class)

Comment: I don't program in c++ from 10 years, I know about namespaces, but I simply forgot to write it. It is simply an oversight. maybe it is better if I delete the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `std::string` instead of `string`.

Also, `std::string` is not polymorphic (does not have virtual function for interface and destruction) so `word` also will not, and cannot be used in place of a string.

Does that match what you are doing?

Comment: Thank you, I don't program in c++ from 10 years, I found the code on a website on string class.