# How can I use the default C++ string constructor in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

So basically, I'm just messing around with classes and functions and such, and one thing I'd like to know is this:

Say I had this class, that derives off of std::string

```
class MyString : public std::string {
};
```

Because I'd like to create variables of type `MyString` that initializes the same way as std::string, I'd attempt to use:

```
using std::string::string;
```

**However,** this doesn't seem to work in Visual Studio - to VS, string() is not a member function.

This works in Code::Blocks / G++, why not Visual Studio / VC++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works in [MSVC2015](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/). VS2013 didn't support inheriting constructors

```
                           2010  2012  2013
Inheriting constructors    No    No    No
```

while MSVC2015 does (from *preview* on): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx

As to why you shouldn't inherit from `std::string`, I recommend this post: [Why should one not derive from c++ std string class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6006860/1938163)

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368(v=vs.140).aspx), inherting constructors is not supported, at least in VS2013 or earlier versions.

But you shouldn't be inheriting from `std::string` anyway. No good will come from that. Write non-member functions if you want to extend the functionality of an existing class.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please correct me if there's something wrong with the answer.