# How can I add member functions in built-in classes in c++?

Tags: c++, string, member-functions

I want to add a new member function "charReplace" to the string class. The function will replace all the occurances of one character with another character. So I prepared a sample code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string string::charReplace(char c1, char c2) { //error in this line
    while(this->find(c1) != std::string::npos) {
        int c1pos = this->find(c1); //find the position of c1
        this->replace(c1pos, 1, c2); //replace c1 with c2
    }
    return *this;
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "sample string";

    s.charReplace('s', 'm') /* replace all s with m */

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

But it is not working. I am getting the following error in line 4 while compiling.

> error: 'string' does not name a type

I know that it is quite easy to get the same result by creating a non-member function. But I want to do it using a member function. So, is there a way to do this in c++?

P.S. I am still new with c++. I have been using it for a few months only. So, please try to make your answer easy to understand.

Comment: However this still wont work, because you cannot / should not edit the string header. So after adding std::, itll still complain about the function, but now that it is not a part of string.

Comment: Here is a better way: [How to replace all ocurrences of a character is a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896600/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-character-in-string)

Comment: string is a rather complex structure (typedef basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > string;) ... i would suggest that you define a new class that contain string, and the new function charReplace

Comment: your `replace` is wrong - you've a wrong amount of parameters (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can't. this is C++, not JavaScript (where you can prototype any classes).

your options are:

1. inheritance
2. composition
3. free standing functions

Comment: Inheritance is the worst option here. Most C++ standard classes are not meant to be inherited from.

Comment: the list has no logic in the order

Comment: But it implies (to me, at least) that these are equally good solutions.

Answer (score 5):

You can't add to the `std::string` interface but you can do this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{ 
    std::string s = "sample string";

    std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 's', 'm'); /* replace all s with m */

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
mample mtring
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message points to this identifier

```
std::string string::charReplace(char c1, char c2) { 
            ^^^^^^
```

that is unknown to the compiler. The compiler knows only `std::string` but it does not know what unqualified identifier `string` means.

But in any case the approach is incorrect because all members of a class shall be declared in the class definition. You may not to add new members of a class without changing its definition.

You can write a non-member function that will do the same task.

Take into account that your function implementation has a serious bug. If arguments `c1` and `c2` specify the same character then the function will have an infinite loop.

I would write the function the following way

```
std::string & charReplace( std::string &s, char c1, char c2 ) 
{
    for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0; 
          ( pos = s.find( c1, pos ) ) != std::string::npos;
          ++pos ) 
    {
        s[pos] = c2;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: for(char&c:s) if(c==c1) c=c2;

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to do it using a member function. So, is there a way to do
>   this in c++?

No.

However, the real question should be: Why?

`std::string` is bloated enough as it is. So much that Herb Sutter once wrote a [GotW article](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm) about it.

In C++, it is very good practice to extend the functionality of a class through free-standing, non-friend functions. This greatly **enhances encapsulation**, because a free-standing, non-friend function cannot access `private` or `protected` members.

If you look at the standard library or the Boost libraries, you will find that this principle is applied a lot. The whole "STL" (= containers/algorithms/iterators) part of the standard library is based on it. The public interfaces of container classes like `std::set` or `std::vector` are not full of functions like `reverse`, `count_if` or `all_of`. There are free-standing functions for that:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of
- etc...

You should follow this excellent example in C++, not work against it.

---

It is *technically* possible to derive from `std::string` and add member functions to the derived class. But this is **bad practice**. Here is a nice question with good answers on the topic, including references to books of renowned experts like Scott Meyers or Andrei Alexandrescu:

[Why should one not derive from c++ std string class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006860/why-should-one-not-derive-from-c-std-string-class)

Finally, note that this kind of consideration is not unique to C++. Take Java, for example. In Java, it is best practice as well to derive *only* from classes which are designed to be base classes. This is even an item in Joshua Bloch's famous "Effective Java" book. In the case of Java's `String` class, you could not even derive from it, of course, because it is `final`. Chances are that if the C++ standard library was designed today, with the new features added in C++11, `std::string` would be `final`, too (even though Bjarne Stroustrup, the inventor of C++, has apparently never been a big fan of final classes, but this is another story).

Comment: GotW link is dead: https://web.archive.org/web/20170714100049/http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (and you should not) change the `std::string` class (in particular, because it is standardized in C++11 and provided by its standard library).

You could subclass `std::string` (but this is often frown upon).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "add" a function to a already defined class.

What you can do is make a stand alone function, called `charReplace`

Comment: Or use `std::replace` :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do add methods to existing classes in C++, unless you directly modify their definition (which you are not supposed to do with standard classes).

Thus, you are limited to two options:

- Subclassing: This is discouraged for standard library classes, unless you know what you are doing. (If you have to ask, you probably aren't. E.G. virtual destructors are an important point here.)
- Adding free functions (or static class functions): In your case, that would be `std::string charReplace(std::string& str, char c1, char c2){...};`, called as `charReplace(s,c1,c2)`. This is the only viable option here.

Comment: *" E.G. virtual destructors are an important point here"* - No, they are not. Deriving from `std::string` would be bad enough, adding a virtual destructor would make things even worse.

Comment: Perhaps what you mean is the attempt to delete a `std::string` polymorphically when it doesn't have a virtual destructor. This is true, of course - but adding a virtual destructor in your derived class won't fix it. It has to be in the base class. So there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I never said that *adding* virtual destructors is important. *Knowing enough about* them, however is. (I.e. why you wouldn't want to add one, or assign an object of the derived class to a ` string*` and delete that.)