# Creating Custom Functions for Strings in C++

Tags: c++, function, class

I have only been using c++ for about a month now and I was wondering if it were possible to create your own custom functions for something like a string.
For example to find the size of a string you do `stringname.size()` But what if I wanted to make a function like `stringname.customfunction()` were I get to decide what `customfunction()` does. I want to do this so I can create a .toLower() function that converts a whole string to lower. I'm sorry if this is a wierd question but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly but you should be able to emulate this by inheriting from `std::string` (or `basic_string<char>`):

```
class mystring : public std::string
{
public:
    void customfunction() { /* ... */ }
};
```

Note: However doing so is a bad idea. In addition to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006860/why-should-one-not-derive-from-c-std-string-class) that [@Cheers and hth. - Alf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688494/creating-custom-functions-for-strings-in-c/33688698?noredirect=1#comment55153599_33688698) mentions, Herb Sutter discusses the overly [wide interface of std::string](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm) and widening it even further is a bad idea.

Comment: SO was very slooooow here for a while, but here's a link to more info: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006860/why-should-one-not-derive-from-c-std-string-class). The accepted and heavily upvoted answer is ungood – not uncommon on SO – but there are good points made.

Comment: I didn't say it was best practice - I merely presented it as a way of doing it.  Where I work we have 6 different string classes, two of which are home grown.  I will update the answer to note that it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can create custom functions, but not directly as member functions of an existing class.

The simplest and therefore best approach is to just create freestanding functions.

That means that you'll call it like `customfunction( s )`.

Comment: so instead of stringname.customfunction() the preferred way is customfunction(string a). Alright I think I understand now.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by creating you own string class, but as I've undertood you mean calling something like `"THE String".toLower()` as in python for example. This is actually imposible in c++ as far as I know.

Once again your best chance is do your own class so you can call someting like `MyString("THE String").toLower()`. Or just create a function toLower that takes an string and return an string `toLower("THE String")`

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit advanced and highly despised, but you could change the actual source files. I highly suggest YOU DO NOT do this.

You should just make a simple function `void toLower(std::string str);` that would convert it for you.
(You would call this function with `toLower(str);`.)