# What should I override in inheritance when it comes to simple derivation?

Tags: c++

```
class MyString :public string {
public:
    using string :: string;
    using string :: operator=;
    bool operator== (MyString&);
    bool operator<  (MyString&);
    bool operator>  (MyString&);
    MyString& operator=  (MyString&);
    MyString& operator=  (string&);
    MyString operator() (int, int);
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream&, MyString&);
};

MyString MyString::operator() (int a, int b) {
    MyString os;
    os = string::substr(a, b);
    return os;
}
```

Note: I'm using cstring

It's my learning experiment.
I am confused when it comes to very simple derivation like code above.

1. Suppose I just want to add feature that can get substring by (int, int) operator, but I realize I can't use those functions that take `MyString` parameters.
2. I have tried to use using for those operators `==`, `<`, `>` but that doesn't work.
   The compiler tells me that string don't have those operator, I wonder it's because those functions in string are not `virtual`?
3. Is the code in `operator()` legal base on my functionality set in `public:`?
   The compiler doesn't tell me any thing. But I'm quite skeptical.

Comment: afaik `std::string`s destructor is non-virtual, ie. it is not really made for inheriting from it

Comment: Do not derive. Especially not from logically sealed classes.

Comment: What is "light derivation"?

Comment: @juanchopanza i didnt dare to ask because I wasnt sure if its just my ignorance or something OP made up ;)

Comment: sorry guys, seems I should avoid using terminology like words.

Comment: Don't inherit from any standard library types that aren't specifically intended to be inherited from (like std::ostream and std::istream are).  Basically, if it doesn't have a virtual destructor, don't inherit.

Comment: @tobi303: thanks! I can understand a lot from your explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do *not* derive from `std::string`. Some reasons are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006860/why-should-one-not-derive-from-c-std-string-class), so I won't repeat them.

If you want to extend functionality of `std::string`, you can either

Make a wrapper class

```
class MyString
{
    std::string underlying_string;
public:
    /* methods */
}
```

Problem is, that it has nothing to do with `std::string` anymore. It can't be assigned to `std::string`, nor passed to function accepting `std::string`<sup>1</sup>. Also it is quite a bit verbose - consider adding all overloads of `operator+` (`std::string + MyString`, `MyString + std::string`, maybe also `MyString + char*`, add `consts` and move semantics) and you are at ~16 methods?

Another option, is to define just helper method.

```
std::string do_super_cool_thing(const std::string& str, int a, int b)
{
    return magic(str, a, b);
}
```

---

1. Can be helped with non-explicit ctor `MyString::MyString(std::string)`, user defined conversion `operator std::string()`, but it has different meaning than inheritance.

Comment: If you want to pass it to a function accepting std::string, you can define `operator std::string()` on the class.   [user-defined conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) can be incredibly useful.