# Select string template implicitly by passing const char*

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have my custom string class:

```
class my_string : public std::string
{
    // ...
}
```

And I want to make a templated function which accepts both with `my_string` by default:

```
template <typename TString = my_string>
TString do_something(const TString& input)
{
    // ...
}
```

But when I call it with:

```
auto result = do_something("abcdef");
```

It calls (of course) `do_something<char[7]>()`. How to force it to call `do_something<my_string>` *without* explicitly specifying the type (i.e. write `do_something("abcdef")`, not `do_something<my_string>("abcdef")`) ?

Comment: Note: Although just an example, never derive from std::string!

Comment: I would just add an overload for `const char[]` and have it forward to the function you want to call.

Comment: Literal string suffix might help as alternative: `"abcdef"s` and with `operator "" _my_s` `"abcdef"_my_s`.

Comment: Why a template? my_string is a std::string (hence std::string should be convertible to my_string)

Comment: @DieterLücking Why not to derive from `std::string`?

Comment: ["Why should one not derive from c++ std string class?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006860/why-should-one-not-derive-from-c-std-string-class)

Comment: @DieterLücking template because I must accept both, and don't want unneeded converting, suppose old legacy code that uses only `std::string` and does not know about `my_string`, function will return `my_string` to it, and I must refactor old legacy code.

Comment: @boris that presumes heap allocation and polymorphic pointers.  `new std::string` and `delete std::string` are already anti-patterns, heap-allocating a heap-allocation manager like `std::string` is code smell.  In a land of smart pointers and value semantics wrappers (aka modern C++) that advice is relatively obsolete.  Smart pointers can store their deleter and should be how the objects are created (no direct calls to `new`), value semantics wrappers either don't call delete or use smart pointers.

Comment: Could you edit the question to clarify what you want the return type to be in this special case? `my_string` or `const char *`?

Answer (score 3):

Particularize for "construct from string arguments".

```
template <typename TString = my_string,
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<std::string, TString>::value>::type = nullptr>
TString do_something(const TString& input)
{
    // ...
}

template <typename ...Args,
typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<my_string, Args....>::value>::type = nullptr>
my_string do_something(Args&&... args)
{
    return do_something<my_string>({args});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a function template? The simple function:

```
my_string do_something(my_string const& input) { ... }
```

solves your use-case. You can pass in a `my_string` or string literal, or even a *braced-init-list* and everything just works.

---

Since you need a template for other reasons, you can simply provide an overload for arrays of `const char`:

```
template <class TString>
TString do_something(TString const&) { ... }

template <size_t N>
my_string do_something(const char (&arr)[N]) {
    return do_something(my_string{arr, N-1});
}
```

---

Note: there's no reason to provide a default for the template parameter `TString`. There's no way for that default to be meaningfully used.

Comment: It returns `my_string`, which I don't want in old code that uses `std::string`.

Comment: Do you really want to take the array by reference here?  I would think a `const char[]` parameter would be more useful as you can pass an array or pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver I would prefer to just capture string literals.

Answer (score 1):

Re

> **”**  I want to make a templated function which accepts both with `my_string` by default

```
#include <string>

template< class Type >
struct Explicit_t_ { using T = Type; };

template< class Type >
using Explicit_ = typename Explicit_t_<Type>::T;

namespace my {
    struct String: std::string { using std::string::string; };
}  // namespace my

template< class Some_string >
auto do_something( Explicit_<Some_string> const& )
    -> Some_string
{ return "Template func!"; }

auto do_something( my::String const& )
    -> my::String
{ return "my::String!"; }

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
auto main()
    -> int
{
    cout << do_something( "" ) << endl;       // Output "my::String!"
    cout << do_something<std::string>( "" ) << endl;
}
```

You can let the overload for `my::String` just forward to the function template, unless you want a more specialized or different implementation.