# Is inheriting from std::string with no additional member a good idea?

Tags: c++, exception, polymorphism

I'm been studying CERT C++ guidelines and I have a question related to [ERR58-CPP. Handle all exceptions thrown before `main()` begins executing](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/ERR58-CPP.+Handle+all+exceptions+thrown+before+main%28%29+begins+executing).

I believe avoiding to use static/global variables is good for tonnes of reasons, and it is not make sense to throw exception before `main()`. Even though, there are some cases that global variables which needs to be constructed before `main()` and wrapping such classes to make their constructor never `throw` is a good idea.

However, Scott Meyers said, one should never derive from `std::string`. ( From  [Why should one not derive from c++ std string class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006860/why-should-one-not-derive-from-c-std-string-class) ) That is possibly due to slicing problems.

Is it okay to deriving from `std::string` with no additional member variable/function and not overriding destructor?

Comment: Why would you want to do this

Comment: @m.m. because std string's constructor could throw.

Comment: You may replace std::string with any kind of third party classes with no virtual destructor.

Comment: You don't need any static allocations to happen before main.  In fact, the common way to avoid the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) is to delay construction of statics until used, which you can defer until after entering `main`.

Comment: Better roll your own `class MyString` which has a `std::string` data member and a conversion operator to `std::string`.  This makes it behave like `std::string` and you can add methods and data member without having to worry about implementation details of `std::string`.

Comment: What about using a helper function to create `std::string` ? Then you can handle exception there.

Comment: If I return `std::string`, then copy assignment operator or move assignment  operator may be called when I assign it to static storage. Copy assignment operator may throw, or none of assignment operator called by RVO.