# Why does std::string("\x00") report length of 0?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring, string-length

I have a function which needs to encode strings, which needs to be able to accept 0x00 as a valid 'byte'. My program needs to check the length of the string, however if I pass in `"\x00"` to `std::string` the `length()` method returns 0.

How can I get the actual length even if the string is a single null character?

Comment: Have a look at the [available constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) and which is used in your case.

Comment: You could also try `strlen("\x00");` for the same result.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210211/access-violation-when-sending-a-0-int-literal-to-a-const-string-parameter/

Comment: Would you not be better to store a vector (other containers are available) of bytes instead of a string?

Comment: @JackAidley the data is coming in as a string, once processed it is stored as a vector of bytes.

Comment: @BoPersson, `strlen(3)` is **not** a C++ function.  It's a C legacy function, that does not know about c++ `string` type.  You cannot use it with `string`s but by converting the `string` to a legacy C `char *` string.  That way, `strlen(3)` doesn't know about array sizes, it only searches for the `\0` char and returns the difference between the pointer passed to it and the place where it found the null char.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're passing in an empty string.  Use `std::string(1, '\0')` instead.

Or `std::string{ '\0' }` (thanks, @zett42)

Comment: Shorter: `std::string{ '\0' }`

Comment: Perhaps coincidentally [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255459/difference-between-c-object-construction-methods) just popped up.

Comment: @zett42: since when exists a constructor of `std::string` with only a single `char` argument?

Comment: @CAF Since C++11. It is the [constructor that takes an initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (9).

Comment: or `std::string("\0", 1)`, or `std::string{ '\0' }`.

Comment: Can use ASCII digit codes for same effect: `std::string{ 0 }` or `std::string(1, 0)`

Answer (score 47):

`std::string` is perfectly capable of storing nulls. However, you have to be wary, as `const char*` is not, and you very briefly construct a `const char*`, from which you create the `std::string`.

```
std::string a("\x00");
```

This creates a constant C string containing only the null character, followed by a null terminator. But C strings don't know how long they are; so the string thinks it runs until the first null terminator, which is the first character. Hence, a zero-length string is created.

```
std::string b("");
b.push_back('\0');
```

`std::string` is null-clean. Characters (`\0`) can be the zero byte freely as well. So, here, there is nothing stopping us from correctly reading the data structure. The length of `b` will be `1`.

In general, you need to avoid constructing C strings containing null characters. If you read the input from a file directly into `std::string` or make sure to push the characters one at a time, you can get the result you want. If you really need a constant string with null characters, consider using some other sentinel character instead of `\0` and then (if you *really* need it) replace those characters with `'\0'` after loading into `std::string`.

Comment: _"But C strings don't know how long they are"_ -- To be more precise, `std::string("\x00")` first creates a *string literal* of type `const char[2]`, so at this point the size is still well known. Though this array decays into `const char*` which is passed to the `std::string` constructor. At this point the array size is "lost" because the constructor can only scan for the 1st `\0` to determine the size. In theory `std::string` c'tor could have an overload for arrays, that would allow embedded `\0` in string literal.

Comment: @zett42 such an overload would have to be templated, and be instantiated for each new length of the array — there's no other native way to pass sized arrays in C++.

Comment: @Ruslan So? That would have been perfectly acceptable. Of course it would also have been silly, as it’d break the C string literal convention and thus violates the user’s expectation in most cases (nobody wants to find a null char in their string when initialising it as `std::string("hi")`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph So, that would generate a new function for each size of string literals passed to `std::string::string`. Not perfect from code size perspective; you'd only have to hope the linker will omit these functions and the compiler inline their code into callers.

Comment: @Ruslan Code inlining wouldn’t reduce code size. On the contrary, to help with generated code size the constructor template could dispatch to a size-erased non-generic function that isn’t inlined. But for this particular constructor, inlining probably works just fine, and results in the same code size regardless of whether you’d have a constructor template or a non-template constructor (since it’s inlined either way).

Comment: @KonradRudolph inlining won't, but creation of additional _callable_ instance of the function will.

Comment: @zett42 We already have `std::string (const char* s, size_t n);` overload, and it can handle dynamically allocated `char` arrays. Calling it as `my_str("\0", ARRAYSIZE("\0"));` is usually a minor inconvenience.

Comment: @Joker_vD Agreed. I wasn't saying that an array overload would actually make sense. I mentioned it solely to underline the fact that the compiler knows the size of a string literal, whether or not it has embedded `\0`s.

Comment: I think you wanted to type `b.push_back('\0');` instead of `a.push_back('\0');`. Apart from this, great answer!

Comment: @FabioTurati It's always the little things that slip by, isn't it? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 24):

With C++14, you can use a [string literal operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) to store strings with null bytes:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

std::string a = "\0"s;
std::string aa = "\0\0"s; // two null bytes are supported too
```

Comment: @sp2danny ... but may also bring in other, unwanted literal operators (e.g. from `std::literals::chrono_literals`).