# Difference between C++ object construction methods

Tags: c++, string, c++11, constructor

The different construction syntaxes in C++ have always confused me a bit. In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255276/why-does-stdstring-x00-report-length-of-0/48255303), it was suggested to try initializing a string like so

```
std::string foo{ '\0' };
```

This works and produces the intended result: a string of length 1 containing only the null character. In testing the code, I accidentally typed

```
std::string foo('\0');
```

This compiles fine (no warnings even with `-Wall`), but terminates at runtime with

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Now, as far as I can tell, [there is no constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) for `std::string` which takes a single character as an argument, and this hypothesis is further confirmed when I attempt to pass the character indirectly.

```
char b = '\0';
std::string a(b);
```

This produces a nice, lengthy compile error. As does this

```
std::string a('z');
```

So my question is: what allows `std::string a('\0');` to compile, and what makes it different from `std::string a{ '\0' };`?

---

<sub>Footnote: Compiling using `g++` on Ubuntu. This doesn't strike me as a compiler bug, but just in case...</sub>

Comment: My wild guess is that this '\0' gets interpreted as 0, and 0 is further thought to be nullptr. "null not valid" seems to back that theory. That said, I'd expect this to at least throw a warning.

Comment: For better or worse, `\0` is a [null pointer constant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL), so `std::string foo('\0');` is equivalent to `std::string foo(NULL);` and calls a constructor taking `char*`. But that constructor doesn't expect `NULL` - passing it exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that since C++14, `'\0'` is not a null pointer constant anymore, so you should get a compile error.

Comment: @Brian Hm... that would be very nice. But even when compiling with `-std=c++14` or `-std=c++17`, it still compiles without an error. Perhaps `g++` hasn't fully implemented the new standard yet.

Comment: [g++ 7 rejects this code.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zN06TRJCX0XAW5CI)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Character `'\0'` is implicitly convertible to integer value of `0` thus representing *implementation-defined null pointer constant*. This:

```
std::string foo('\0');
```

calls a constructor overload accepting pointer of type `const char*` as a parameter and results in undefined behavior. 
 It is equivalent to passing `0` or `NULL`:

```
std::string foo(0); // UB
std::string bar(NULL); // UB
```

The [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) for the 4th and 5th constructor overloads states:

> The behavior is undefined if s... including the case when s is a **null
>   pointer**.

The second statement:

```
std::string foo{'\0'}; // OK
```

calls a constructor accepting `std::initializer_list<char>` as a parameter and does not cause UB.

You could call the constructor overload accepting *count* number of `char`s instead:

```
std::string s(1, '\0');
```

Answer (score 0):

With `C++ 14` or `C++17` or `C++11`, this undefined behavior results in a compile error in both `clang5.0` and `gcc7.2`.

```
#include<string> 
std::string S('\0');
```

> error: no matching function for call to
>   'std::__cxx11::basic_string::basic_string(char)'  std::string
>   S('\0');
>                      ^

The UB is fixed(to give a compiler error) in recent compiler versions.