# C++11 Template function to "implicity" convert bitset<N> to "unsigned long"

Tags: c++, c++11, bitset

I can create a C++11 Template function to explicitly convert a bitset into an unsigned long:

```
template<size_t N>
unsigned long U(bitset<N> x) {
    return x.to_ulong();
}

// Explicit conversion
unsigned long y = U(bitset<4>("1010"));
```

Is there a way to "implicitly" convert bitset to an unsigned long using a C++11 template helper function.  For Example, if I assign a bitset to an unsigned long, then I want it to automatically convert the bitset to the correct type:

```
// What Template Function in C++11?

// Implicit Conversion
unsigned long z = bitset<4>("1010");
```

(If its not possible to create an implicit convertion rule to convert to "unsigned long using a C++11 template function, its also acceptable to derive a new class from bitset that has casting function to unsigned long.  Is that possible as well?)

Comment: Is `unsigned long z = bitset<4>("1010").to_ulong();` acceptable?

Comment: no, because it too messy to keep converting it....  I have it used in complicated Boolean equations across several files... it just looks ulgy if its not implicitly converted...

Comment: To be honest, if your bitset is not too big, you could directly use a binary literal: `auto z = 0b1010ul;`. On the other hand having `bitset` implicitly convertible to `unsigned long` might cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: that's a good point... except, I really want to use bitset because it has bounds checking and doesn't allow my inputs to go out of of range of the specified number of bits.

Comment: Ok, agreed.  If you are writing normal programmer code it’s good enough to use c++14 0b0010...etc, But, I would like to keep track of bit widths because it’s modeling hardware in c++ like verilog, systemc, vhdl. etc.

Comment: I thought about just throwing away bitset and creating a class wrapper around uint64_t instead that enforces a given bit width onto input and output variables to logical function as a sanity check of doing all the logic equations in 64 bit ints.

Comment: It would be nice if for instance the bitset replacement class could keep track of how the bitwidths expand when you add or multiple bit vectors of different bit lengths...but I suppose I can just hand calculate the bit width of the final result and assign the truncation width for output bit vector using uint64_t class wrapper... if that makes sense to anyone..

Answer (score 7):

To *implicitly* convert `A` to `B`, either:

- `B` must have a non-explicit constructor taking `A`, or
- `A` must have a non-explicit conversion `operator B()`.

Both of these must be member functions only.

Since you cannot modify `std::bitset` or `unsigned long` the answer is: no, you cannot *implicitly* convert `std::bitset` to `unsigned long`. Only *explicitly*.

Comment: I'm willing to derive a new class from bitset to fix the problem.. how would you do it in this case?

Comment: For most `std` classes, you are [not supposed to derive from them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006860/why-should-one-not-derive-from-c-std-string-class). You could encapsulate it in a new class though.

Comment: Is this possible in C++11:  template<size_t N> operator unsigned long(bitset<N>& x) {return x.to_ulong();}    ??  (A helper function that satisfies bullet two)

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap `std::bitset` in your own implicitly convertible class:

```
template<size_t N>
class MyBitset
{
public:
    // constructors elided here

    operator unsigned long()
    {
        return _bitset.to_ulong();
    }

    operator std::bitset<N>()
    {
        return _bitset; // Note that you get a copy here.
    }

private:
    std::bitset<N> _bitset;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/euuB3f)

If you are trying to derive from non-polymorphic classes in `namespace std` (i.e. those without virtual destructors), you are [not writing idiomatic C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006860/why-should-one-not-derive-from-c-std-string-class), don't do it. Whether the above is really a solution to your problem we can't tell. If all you need is `unsigned long` constants from your bitstrings, you could skip the class wrapper and replace its constructors with templated functions directly:

```
template<size_t N, class CharT>
unsigned long toUlong(const CharT* str,
                 typename std::basic_string<CharT>::size_type n =
                     std::basic_string<CharT>::npos,
                 CharT zero = CharT('0'),
                 CharT one = CharT('1'))
{
    return std::bitset<N>(str, n, zero, one).to_ulong();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/YJxJeG)

Comment: I like this idea of using a wrapper... it hides all the public functions of bitset and lets you define your own...

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution based on Maxim's Bullet 2:

```
template<size_t N>
class bits : public bitset<N> {
public:
    bits(unsigned long num) : bitset<N>(num) {}
    bits(char* binstr) : bitset<N>(binstr){}

    operator unsigned long() {
        return this->to_ulong();
    }

    // Slice Bit Range
    unsigned long slice(unsigned L, unsigned R)
    {
        unsigned long P1;
        unsigned long P2;

        if (L>R) {
            P2 = L;
            P1 = R;
        }
        else {
            P2 = R;
            P1 = L;
        }

        unsigned long x = this->to_ulong();
        unsigned long W = P2 - P1 + 1;

        unsigned long Value = (x >> P1) & ((1<<W) - 1);

        return Value;
    }

    // Return Hex String
    string hstr() {
        stringstream xx;
        xx << "0x" << hex << this->to_ulong();
        return xx.str();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Implicit conversion...
    unsigned long xxx = bits<4>("0101");
    unsigned long yyy = bits<4>(xxx).slice(1, 2);
}
```