# C++ inherited operator implicit conversion

Tags: c++, inheritance, implicit-conversion

I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A : public std::string {
public:
  A(int){};
};

int main() {
  A a(5);
  std::cout << (a == A(5)) << std::endl;
  std::cout << (a == 5) << std::endl;
}
```

The first line works, the number is explicit converted to an "A" and then the comparison operator from `std::string` is used to compare the object.

My problem is that I want to avoid the explicit conversion, but if I do it like in the second line, the compiler doesn't recognize the possibility to implicit convert the number and than use the `std::string` comparison.

Is there a way to change the class A in such a way, that the implicit convert/comparison work?

Comment: The `std::`types were not designed to be inherit from (unless explicitly noted).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should one not derive from c++ std string class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006860/why-should-one-not-derive-from-c-std-string-class)

Comment: The best thing to do by a country mile here is to have a `std::string` as a member of `A`. Then implement the operators &c. as you need.

Comment: Thats's because the `operator==` is defined as a template, so the type deduction occurs (and fails) before the parameter conversion is considered.

Comment: What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you think using inheritance of `std::string` will solve that problem?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Its a legacy code, so I do not know why they decided to to so, but they did.

Comment: _"... comparison operator from std::string is used to compare the object...."_ but as `std::string` does not know about `class A` the sliced object is test for equality not the whole object.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But the idea of inheriting from std::string was, that we want to create a class, that have all features of a std::string, but a few additional methods.

Comment: @gerum Does your real code have member variables added in `A` so it's not just a `std::string` with some extra member functions?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, there are no member variables added.

Comment: Someone, somewhere did a very bad design choice. I'm sorry you have to live through maintaining such code.

Comment: @gerum Ok, then perhaps [this](https://godbolt.org/z/5crehKGhM)? I'm a bit reluctant to putting it up as an answer though :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can solve your problem with a [user-defined conversion function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

In your case you could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A : public std::string {
public:
    A(int i) : m_i { i } {};
    operator int() const { return m_i; }
    int m_i;
};

int main() {
    A a(5);
    std::cout << (a == A(5)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (a == 5) << std::endl;
}
```

Note however that, as pointed out in comments, you should not derive from `std::string`.

Comment: I will try this version, I must investigate if it is resonable in my real code.